# How to use Application.Match and ignore the first zeros in a string?

Tags: excel, vba

Here is my code but the problem is sometimes, my strings (in a loop) have some zeros in the beginning. So   I would like to ignore them :

```
Dim TableControle As ListObject
Set TableControle = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Test").ListObjects("myTable")

'Loop on all lines
For i = 1 To LastRow
           
 Dim matchResult As Variant
 Dim searchFichier As String
 'my value to search
 searchFichier = "123"
        
 'The value in the columns TableControle.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange could be 00123 or 00456, with 0 in the beginning
  matchResult = Application.Match(searchFichier, TableControle.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, 0)
    
  If IsError(matchResult) Then
   'not found
  Else
   'value found
  End If
    
Next i
```

I tried to use .Find but it indicates a compilation error (surely I don't know how to use it) :

```
 matchResult = .Find(What:=mySearch, _
        LookAt:=TableControle.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange, _
        MatchCase:=False)
```

Could you help me?

Thanks !

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] including some example data. Also include what `mySearch` is and what you expect as result.

Comment: `LookAt:` should be `xlWhole` or `xlPart`.  Try first *looking at* Help for  the `Range.Find` method to get the arguments correct, and, because of the problem with defaults, specify all of the parameters.

Comment: The post has been edited with a full code example.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that if you define `Dim searchFichier As String` it is looking for the text `"123"` but not for a number. Since you probably have numbers in your column it does not match anything.

Therfore you have to change it to

```
Dim searchFichier As Long
searchFichier = 123
```

for example then it will find a number.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The fact is that sometimes, I have this value in my table : "000123.34 " OR "111/234.45". That's why I thought to use string.

Comment: Well then you might want to try `Variant`

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work better with Variant. I will try with the find function (and learn how it workds). Is that a better option?

Comment: Actually mixing numbers and text in one column is always bad. If you have numbers only in that column make sure they are converted into text. If your cell has `123` tun it into `'123` the apostroph will not be shown, but it will handle it as text and it will be found `As String`.